# Pandas & Python: Is there a way to import the contents of an excel file, add text content to the end of the file, and save down?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of names that are stored in an excel file. The user needs to be able to import that list, which is a single column, and add additional names to the list, and save down the file.

I've imported the excel file using pandas and created a dataframe (df). I've tried to append the df using a loop function.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

path = 'C:\\NY_Operations\\EdV\\Streaman\\Python\\CES Fee Calc\\'
file_main = 'Main.xlsx'
df_main = pd.read_excel(path + file_main)

while True:
    b = (input("Enter name of new deal to be added to 'Main' spreadsheet or type 'Exit' "))
    df_main.append(b)
    if df_main [-1] == "Exit":
        df_main.pop()
        break
```

The spreadsheet has "Toy", "Color", "Ball" in A1, A2, and A3. The user should be prompted to add new deals and he/she adds "Watch" and "Belt" and then writes "Exit" and the loop ends. In the spreadsheet, A4 should show "Watch" and A5 should show "Belt" in the df and spreadsheet.

Comment: if you're successfully adding to your `df`, did you try the [`DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: I'm actually having trouble adding the items to the DF. I'm receiving an Error: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'str'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. Thanks for everyone's help.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#create list of deals in the 'main' consolidation spreadsheet

path = 'C:\\NY_Operations\\EdV\\Streaman\\Python\\CES Fee Calc\\'
file_main = 'Main.xlsx'

df_main = pd.read_excel(path + file_main)

new_deals = [] #each entry is the name of the item purchased

while True:
    g = (input("Enter name of item or exit "))
    new_deals.append(g)
    if new_deals [-1] == "exit":
        new_deals.pop()
        break
df_newdeals = pd.DataFrame({'Deal Name':new_deals})

df1 = pd.concat([df_main,df_newdeals])

print(df1)
df1.to_excel(path + file_main)
```